# Refreshing the checkbox within the datagrid

Tags: c#

Hey guys i have one problem in refreshing the checkbox withing the data grid.
While i click the refresh button all the checkbox becomes clear but the checkbox which was clicked at last still seems to be checked.The code which i was used are:

```
  private void cmbrefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clearfields();
            Btncontrols();
            chkbranches.Checked = false;
            gridviewholiday.Refresh();

            gridviewholiday.ClearSelection();

            chkbranches.Checked = false;


            for (int i = 0; i!=gridviewholiday.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                gridviewholiday[0, i].Value = null;

            }

        }
```

Comment: you may look at this link.http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/adding-a-gridview-column-of-checkboxes-cs